# How can I update metric values in Grafana panels via REST API

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

There are panels on the dashboards:

[image]

On the **right panel**, free disk space is displayed, the value comes from the zabbix-agent.
On the **left panel** I want to display my custom values through Grafana REST Api.
I found a way to change the whole dashboard, but I did not find a way to change the values of the panels themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grafana's HTTP APIs are only for managing the tool from dashboard operations to user management etc., not for data manipulation or creation. In other words, values are shown on your dashboard always come from data sources, hence cannot be set using Grafana's RESTful APIs. If you want to create fake data for any panel in your dashboard, Grafana has a solution for this called "TestData" data source. It is disabled by default, but can be easily enabled using the Plugins section. More information can be found at [this link](https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/testdata/).

Comment: With your help, decided to implement through an intermediate database. Next, in the settings datasource connected to this database and then in the settings panel pulled the necessary data through SQL queries.